# MATLAB 3D lines are invisible

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, 3d

Hello I'am suffered from a problem

[image]
[image]

As you can see I want a draw 3D graph.
Problem is when I draw sphere lines are invisible.

Here is simple version of my source

```
    clear all; close all; clc

n=1;
n_inner_drone=3;
n_outter_drone=2;

length=100;

initial_d = zeros(1,n);
inner_x = zeros(n_inner_drone,n);
inner_y = zeros(n_inner_drone,n);
inner_z = zeros(n_inner_drone,n);
outter_x = zeros(n_outter_drone,n);
outter_y = zeros(n_outter_drone,n);
outter_z = zeros(n_outter_drone,n);

radius= length;

disp('test');

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Sphere
% figure()
% [x, y, z] = sphere;
% h = surfl(x*length, y*length, z*length);
% hSurf = surf(X,Y,Z,'EdgeColor','none','LineStyle','none','FaceLighting','phong');
% set(h, 'FaceAlpha', 0.05)
% surf(x*length, y*length, z*length, 
% shading interp
hold on
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

for i=1:n_inner_drone 
    k=1;
    while 1

        x_temp= randi([-length, length], 1, 1);
        y_temp= randi([-length, length], 1, 1);
        z_temp= randi([-length, length], 1, 1);

        dist = sqrt(x_temp^2 + y_temp^2 + z_temp^2);

        if dist<radius
            if i==1
                initial_d(k) = dist;
            end
            inner_x(i,k) = x_temp;
            inner_y(i,k) = y_temp;
            inner_z(i,k) = z_temp;
            k = k+1;
        end

    if k == n+1, break, end
    end
end

ideal_direction_length = ones(1,n);
ideal_direction_length = ideal_direction_length * length;
ideal_direction_length = ideal_direction_length - initial_d;

k=1;

random_x = inner_x(1,:);
random_y = inner_y(1,:);
random_z = inner_z(1,:);

random_moving_distance = zeros(1,n);
moving_distance = 0; 
trigger = 0;
while 1

    if trigger == 0
        direction = randi([1, 6], 1, 1); 
        trigger = 1; 
    end 

    if direction == 1
        random_x(k) = random_x(k) + 1;

    elseif direction == 2
        random_x(k) = random_x(k) - 1;

    elseif direction == 3
        random_y(k) = random_y(k) + 1;

    elseif direction == 4
        random_y(k) = random_y(k) - 1;

    elseif direction == 5
        random_z(k) = random_z(k) + 1;

    elseif direction == 6
        random_z(k) = random_z(k) - 1;
    end

    dist = sqrt(random_x(k)^2 + random_y(k)^2 + random_z(k)^2);
    moving_distance = moving_distance+1;

     %%%%%%%%%% Line
     plot3(random_x(n),random_y(n),random_z(n),'k+')
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    if dist>radius
        random_moving_distance(k) = moving_distance;
        k = k+1;
        moving_distance = 0;
        trigger = 0;    
    end

    if k == n+1, break, end
end 

plot3(inner_x(1,n),inner_y(1,n),inner_z(1,n),'r*')
for k=2:n_inner_drone
    plot3(inner_x(k,n),inner_y(k,n),inner_z(k,n),'b*')
end
for k=1:n_outter_drone
    plot3(outter_x(k,n),outter_y(k,n),outter_z(k,n),'k*')
end
```

At the first, I suspected I worngly draw lines, but without sphere I can see lines as fig2.

Those anyone who knows about this problem.

Please answer to me and I will very appericiate about it.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try setting the `EdgeLines` or `EdgeColor` property on `h` the way you set the `FaceAlpha`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that.

Comment: yeah, now with K+ works with and without an sphere. No lines, just a bunch of points.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because:

```
plot3(gravity_x(n),gravity_y(n),gravity_z(n))
```

is **not** a line. Its a single point.

```
plot3(gravity_x(n:n+1),gravity_y(n:n+1),gravity_z(n:n+1))
```

is a line.

Comment: Oh my explanation was not enough. under the while, all plot3s are single points. line is "plot3(random_x(n),random_y(n),random_z(n),'g-')"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Okay I will make simple code to show you.

Comment: I modified my source code. my orginal source code is too long, hence I made simple version of my source. This source code has same problem. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @JinhyeokKang but I cant reproduce your problem. If I remove the sphere the lines are not drawn. And as I say, If I run `plot3(random_x(n),random_y(n),random_z(n),'g-')` it does not plot a line. Because it is a sinlge point

Comment: Yes It is a single point, but its axis consecutively move to specific point, as result It could draw a line. And you should not remove "hold on" line of sphere part to see a line.

Comment: @JinhyeokKang "but its axis consecutively move to specific point" huh? What does this mean? Really, you can not plot3 single points. If I leave the hold on no lines are drawn either.

Comment: I mean even plot3 is a single point I draw a lot of points hence, it looks like a line.

Comment: That is not how it works.... Take a pen, draw a lot of points. Are they a line? nope. @JinhyeokKang . Also, when plot3 is called with a single point, its so small it can not be seen, basically its not there. You could know this if you have tried, of course.

Comment: As I think lot of points could be line and lot of lines could be side. Anyway even points couldn't be a line, it could similar with line as shown in fig2. In this question I don't need perfect line I'm just wanting tracking point's movement.

Comment: @JinhyeokKang We can do 2 things: First is discuss forever in the comments about what is a line and whatsoever. Second, try the thing, see it for yourself. It is not, no matter how hard you believe on it, if you `plot3` a single point nothing is drawn on screen. try the following code: `hold on;plot3(3,3,3);plot3(2,2,2)`

Comment: Oh I guess why you can't see a line is could be colour of line. Let's try change source code to this  "plot3(random_x(n),random_y(n),random_z(n),'k+')"

Comment: @JinhyeokKang I cant see a line because there is no line. I used the code **you provided**. Also try `hold on;plot3(3,3,3,'k+');plot3(2,2,2,'k+')`  **THERE IS NO LINE**

Comment: You can change your `'g-'` (note the dash means **line**) to `go` or `g*` or `g+` or any other if you want  points to be drawn. But no lines with single points

Comment: I modify figure to explain what I want. I am very sorry for disrupt you due to my lack of english and knowledge. Sometimes current source code shows likes fig1 because points are drawn to random axis so, you can see black group of points if you change view angle as shown in fig2.

Comment: @JinhyeokKang its not lack of english. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Sorry Ander Biguri . It is my first time to using this site. I am agree with my question wasn't well prepared. I will well prepare to ask next time.